# Time-Variant Eigenvalue Dilemma

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, eigenfunctions

I've got this problem where it is the diffusion equation with a source term in $ x : [0,L]$.

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = D_V \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial \bar{c}}{\partial t} $

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{x = 0} +\beta_1(t)v|_{x = 0} = 0 $

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{x = L} = 0$

$v(x,0) = c_0 - \bar{c}(t=0)$

Here $\bar{c}(x,t) = \frac{g_1(t)}{\beta_1(t)}$, where $\beta_1$ and $g_1$ are functions of time, $t$. What makes it tricky is that one of my boundary conditions, despite being homogenous, has a coefficient that is time-variant. So while trying to use the method of eigenfunction expansion, I found time-variant eigenvalues, $\lambda_n$, of the following form with the corresponding eigenfunctions, $f_n(x,t)$:

$tan(\lambda_nL) = \frac{-\beta_1(t)}{g_1(t)}$, where $\lambda_n > 0$

$f_n(x,t) = cos(x\lambda_n) - \frac{\beta_1(t)}{\lambda_n}sin(x\lambda_n) $

From this I know that the solution will be of the following form:

$v(x,t) = \sum T_n(t)f_n(x,t)$

Where $T_n(t) = exp[D_V \int_0^t\lambda_n(\tau)d\tau]\int_0^t(exp[-D_V \int_0^t\lambda_n(\tau)d\tau]\frac{2\bar{c}(\tau)}{L}\int_0^Lf_n(x,t)dx)d\tau$.

The issue is that I've never encountered time-variant eigenvalues and I'm not sure how to approach this situation since the eigenvalues are time-variant. Is there something I'm missing? I'm still pretty new to this subject.

Comment: What's your question? You appear to have a solution.

Comment: @1Rock, just edited the question.

Comment: Your shift transformation of the PDE that you are actually trying to solve is not correct, as I mentioned in the other question. Pushing some details aside, you want $L_1 c =0$ as the PDE and $L_2 c = g$ as the BC.  So given a fixed $c_0$ with $Lc=g$ you write $c=c_0 + c_1$ and then $L_1 c_1 = -L_1 c_0$ and $L_2 c_1 = 0$. For your heat equation $L_1 c_1 = -L_1 c_0$ reads $\partial_t c_1 - D_V \partial_{xx} c_1 = -\partial_t c_0 + D_V \partial_{xx} c_0$. This is *not* what you have written.

Comment: Anyway I would be interested to see an actual derivation of your expression for a single separable solution, because I don't think it can possibly be correct. The whole idea in separation of variables is if $c(x,t)=T(t) X(x)$ then $c_t - c_{xx} = T'(t) X(x) - T(t) X''(x) = 0$ and so $X''/X=T'/T$ but the LHS is a function only of $x$ and the RHS is a function only of $t$ so they must both be constant, which is where the eigenfunctions actually come into play. Your $T(t) f(x,t)$ ansatz destroys this structure so I don't see how it helps.

Comment: @Ian, Thanks for your correspondence. I've learned a lot in the process of exploring this question. And you're right, I have destroyed this structure. Haha.